# Android Cordova - override user changes in font size

Tags: android, cordova

I have a pretty large Cordova app and want to ignore any user changes to the Android system font size.  I've tried various solutions and nothing is working for me.  There's an old plugin that no longer works: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-mobile-accessibility.

Any ideas?  Example code?  I'm not a Java expert - which could the problem when I try to integrate some code snippets.

I'm using Cordova 10.0.0 and Android 9.0.0.

Thanks!  - Jon

Comment: Should be this in Index from what the doc says but It's not working either <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height">

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the plugin does work!  Tested on three Android devices including Android OS 11 and Android OS 12.  Phew!